# Lambdify a function in two variables and plot a surface

Tags: numpy, sympy

I have a function `f(x,y)` where `t` is a parameter. I'm trying to plot the function where `t = 1` for x and y values ranging from -5 to 5. The plot doesn't render.

```py
import sympy as sp 
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
%matplotlib notebook

C = sv.CoordSys3D("")
x, y, z = C.base_scalars()
t = sp.symbols("t")

f = sp.sin(2*sp.pi*t)*sp.exp(-(x-3*sp.sin(sp.pi*t))**2 -(y-3*sp.cos(sp.pi*t))**2)

fig    = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
ax     = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')

X = np.linspace(-5,5,100)
Y = np.linspace(-5,5,100)

xvals, yvals = np.meshgrid(X,Y)
zvals = sp.lambdify((x,y),f.subs(t,1),"numpy")(xvals,yvals)

ax.plot_surface(xvals,yvals,zvals)

plt.show()
```

I get an error `'int' object has no attribute 'ndim'` which I don't know how to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you execute `f.subs(t,1)` it returns a number (zero in this case). So, `f=0` is the expression that you are going to lambdify. Let's see the function generated by `lambdify`:

```py
import inspect
print(inspect.getsource(sp.lambdify((x,y),f.subs(t,1),"numpy")))
# def _lambdifygenerated(Dummy_25, Dummy_24):
#    return 0
```

So, no matter the values and shape of `xvals` and `yvals`, that numerical function will always return `0`, which is an integer number.

However, `ax.plot_surface` requires `zvals` to have the same shape as `xvals` or `yval`. Luckily, we can easily fix that with a simple `if` statement:

```py
import sympy as sp 
import sympy.vector as sv 
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

C = sv.CoordSys3D("")
x, y, z = C.base_scalars()
t = sp.symbols("t")

f = sp.sin(2*sp.pi*t)*sp.exp(-(x-3*sp.sin(sp.pi*t))**2 -(y-3*sp.cos(sp.pi*t))**2)

fig    = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
ax     = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')

X = np.linspace(-5,5,100)
Y = np.linspace(-5,5,100)

xvals, yvals = np.meshgrid(X,Y)
zvals = sp.lambdify((x,y),f.subs(t,1),"numpy")(xvals,yvals)

# if zvals is just a number, create a proper matrix
if not isinstance(zvals, np.ndarray):
    zvals = zvals * np.ones_like(xvals)

ax.plot_surface(xvals,yvals,zvals)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The fact that this doesn't render is bug in `lambdify` that it doesn't work well for constant expressions.

Your real problem though is that the expression you are trying to plot is just zero:

```
In [5]: f
Out[5]: 
                    2                    2           
 - (x_ - 3⋅sin(π⋅t))  - (y_ - 3⋅cos(π⋅t))            
ℯ                                         ⋅sin(2⋅π⋅t)

In [6]: f.subs(t, 1)
Out[6]: 0
```